# Identifying Bootloader ttyACM# device

Tags: bootloader

I'm using a modified version of Arduino Zero Bootloader. I am trying to write software to automatically detect which USB device the bootloader is currently running on in order to execute bossac.

I have noticed a few unique characteristics when using "lsusb -v". Things like "bDeviceClass" is always 2. and "bDeviceSubClass" is always 0; However, I do not feel confident in using these traits to identify the bootloader. Is there any clear indication of bootloader so I can find the correct ttyACM#?

Comment: Have you tried `ls -l /dev/serial/by-id`? On my Ubuntu, it shows aliases with rather indicative names (ProductID in particular) and the alias points to the right ttyACM#.

Answer (score 1):

The only things you have at your disposal are what is in `lsusb -v`. Using those you can craft a `udev` rule to create a symlink to a unique device name. I do that with all my boards so that they all get a unique name.

Here is one of my rules:

```
ATTRS{idVendor}=="2341", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0042",  
  ATTRS{serial}=="95336333635351F091B1", KERNEL=="ttyACM*", 
  MODE="0660", GROUP="plugdev", SYMLINK+="board/arduino/mega2560"
```

That links `/dev/board/arduino/mega2560` to whatever `/dev/ttyACM*` node got created when it was plugged in.  That is in `/etc/udev/rules.d/50-boards.rules`

More on udev here: http://playground.arduino.cc/Linux/Udev

A useful command is `udevadm info -a -n /dev/ttyACM0` which lists all the attributes for that device which you can then use in the `udev` rule.