# Reprogram By Address: Arduino Node Array

Tags: arduino-uno, atmega328

Let me just start off by saying that this is the first time I've attempted a project at this scale. I'm not sure that I'm even taking the right approach on this.

I'm attempting a project inspired by [Daniel Rozin](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kV8v2GKC8WA). This is basically an array of small stepper motors representing display pixels, where it's lighter when pointing towards a reference light and darker as it's points away. Each Arduino controls two steppers through two ULN2003 drivers. These nodes will be given instructions by a raspberry-pi via i2c or spi.

*My question is this:* One of my goals is to reprogram the ATmega328Ps through the raspberry pi without taking down the entire display and reprogramming each of the nodes individually. I would expect my code to go through a number of iterations, and reprogramming these individually sounds like a nightmare. Is it possible to reprogram these nodes by address from the raspberry-pi? Is this a problem that should be tackled using some standard mechanism?

Here is what I'm currently thinking about. And I'm not an expert here. I could be way off base. I don't know... According to [this writeup](https://www.baldengineer.com/arduino-bootloader.html), when the application starts, the bootloader is looking for a series of byes to kick off the reprogramming process. What I'm thinking about is forking the arduino bootloader project and defining a different expected series of bytes for each node.

Comment: thank you for responding, @jsotola. I've edited my question to try and make it a little clearer... The question is specific about programming multiple Arduinos... I would expect the code to go through a number of iterations and the idea to pulling the display down and programming them individually sounds like a nightmare.

Comment: I would consider a WiFi/BT platform that supports OTA updates--it's unclear how the nodes would be symchronized from the description. Note that such a node can be *very* cheap, on the order of 5-10 dollars, and in the end, a matrix display like this needs little in the way of smarts.

Comment: Is is really worth it doing all this work just to reprogram them easier? As I understood the Arduinos will just move the motors to a specific position like commanded by the Pi. Thats a rather easy code. Normally one would do the development with only very few Arduinos (main code with only one, testing communication with maybe 3). Scaling to a full display can be done later, when the Arfuino code doesn't really chamge anymore. Also you didn't specify how exactly the Arduinos are connected to the Pi

Comment: If your question is how to address the individual Arduinos from Linux (which is, I guess, what the Raspberry Pi will be running), see [this answer](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/a/28203).